# is it possible to set letter spacing in cytoscape?

Tags: css, cytoscape.js

Is it possible to set letter spacing for labels in cytoscape? Small labels result in very spacey text.

[spaced out letters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MErjE.png)

Comment: I assume you are talking about cytoscape.js, and not cytoscape desktop.  You should change your tag to be cytoscape.js.

Comment: There seems to be no property for this in cytoscape.js, I would suggest a feature request on the official GitHub page if you really need this.